# Dynamically add a button to a view from a listview Adapter GetView method

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, xamarin.android, android-adapter

As a little eperiment, I'm trying to do the following.

I have an AXML describing a vertical linear layout which contains a listview (only filling 200dp of the vertical linear layout ). The AXML is inflated when the activity starts with SetContentView. Then the listview is correctly populated with values using its Adapter.

In the GetView method of the listview Adapter, I am trying to also dynamically create a button and add it to the linear layout, but for some reason the button is not added.

If I try to add the button in the constructor method of the Adapter instead, it is correctly added.

Can you tell me what could be possibly going wrong?

Let me add some code:

```
class TracksAdapter : BaseAdapter<string> {

        Activity context;
        List<Dictionary<string,string>> trackList;

        // constructor
        public TracksAdapter (Activity context, List<Dictionary<string,string>> trackList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.trackList = trackList;

            // Just as a little test, if I create the button from here it will be correctly added to linear layout: 
            var ll = context.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linLayForResultsActivity);
            Button b1 = new Button(context);
            b1.Text = "Btn";
            ll.AddView(b1);

        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View oldView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // if I create the button from here it will not be added to the layout
            var ll = context.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linLayForResultsActivity);
            Button b1 = new Button(context);
            b1.Text = "Btn";
            ll.AddView(b1);

            // this other code is working
            View view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ResultItem, null);
            var artistLabel = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.resultArtistNameTextView);
            artistLabel.Text = trackList[position]["trackArtistName"];
            return view;
        }
}
```

---

**Update**: adding some more context information because I know this can be a bit weird to understand without it:

In GetView, I **don't** need to return the new button I am trying to create there. GetView only need to return a listview view item, but, along its execution, GetView also has to create and add a button to the linear layout containing the listview.

The real code is much more complex than that. I have simplified it in the question. In the real code, the listview items are made of text and a button. The GetView also attaches event handlers to the buttons. Then what I need is, when a user clicks a button in any of the listview items, another button is added below the listview. So I need the code for adding another button to be in GetView, and the button needs to be added *outside* of the listview, ie. to the linear layout containing the listview.

Comment: if you share your code, it would be easier for others to help you

Comment: actually the function is called getView not GetView

Comment: I am using Xamarin :)

Comment: ah ok! I didn't get that

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xamarin but in Android Studio we do the following : LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); b1.setLayoutParams(params); ll.AddView(b1);

Comment: But the button is added correctly even without any parameters if I make it in the adapter constructor... it's exactly the same code...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108926/discussion-between-pooya-and-jj).

Answer (score 0):

Use the LayoutInflator to create a view based on your layout template, and then inject it into the view where you need it.

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

// fill in any details dynamically here
TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.a_text_view);
textView.setText("your text");

// insert into main view
ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.insert_point);
insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Comment: the OP wants dynamic creation of the group not inflation

Answer (score 0):

I looked in you code, you are returning **view**, while you add the button to **ll**, you should return **ll**

what you return in getView() is what you see in the list item layout, since you're adding the button to **ll** and returning **view**, the button won't appear.

you can add the button to **view** as you implementation

Also check this:
Try using `boolean addViewInLayout (View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addViewInLayout(android.view.View, int, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more, how this can help? The documentation says: *Adds a view during layout. This is useful if in your onLayout() method, you need to add more views* but I don't need to add it at that time? I need it to be added from GetView method...

Comment: No, I need to return the view for the listview item. I don't need to return ll, ll is not part of the listview, it's just some other piece of UI I want to add contextually to when GetView is called.

Comment: Then you can add the button to view

Comment: That's what I am trying to do... please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

It's working... Without making any changes now it's working as it should... ! Ugh!
I really don't know what I was doing wrong here... probably it was because of some sort of caching of older version of the installed APK.. ? I know this sort of stuff can happen, and that's why I've always been uninstalling the app before deplyoing the new version to the device... but still...!